# Convert ((ba ∪ ab)∗ ∪ b)* to NFA

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

How do I simplify this $((ba \cup ab)^∗ \cup b)^*$?  I can draw the NFA for the '$ba$', '$ab$' and '$b$' term but when it comes to linking the '$ba \cup ab$' to the '$)^∗ \cup b)^*$' i am unsure how to draw the asterisk. Is it just an epsilon transition back to the starting state?

Comment: Use epsilon for branching to handle multiple simultaneous states. If you then convert your NFA to a DFA, and minimise the DFA. Then convert the DFA back again to the expression, you'll get a simplified expression. Bit of work though.

Comment: Building blocks: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-conversion-of-a-regular-expression-to-finite-automata-nfa#:~:text=Category-,What%20is%20the%20conversion%20of%20a,to%20finite%20Automata%20(NFA)%3F&text=A%20Regular%20Expression%20is%20a,convert%20Regular%20Expression%20into%20NFA.

Answer (score 0):

The $*$ (kleene closure) allows you to have 0 or more instances of the string so think of it as a self loop. Think of union as different paths. So you can have something like a state where on $ab$ or $ba$ you reach the same state and on a $b$ to another state. You can do it with epsilon transitions too, but in this case they don't seem necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, the number of epsilons can probably be reduced though:

[image]